# How we append value in Array in swift2

Tags: swift2

I want to append selectedtime value in timeworkLabelArray . But I am getting error  Cannot invoke 'appendContentOf' with argument list of type (String,String)

```
var selectedTime = ("00", "00")
var timeWorkLabelArray = [String]()
timeWorkLabelArray.appendContentsOf(selectedTime)
```

Comment: selectedTime is not an array. You have to write like `var selectedTime = ["00", "00"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is declared as `[String]` but the argument is a tuple `(String, String)`.

Either

```
var selectedTime = ["00", "00"]
var timeWorkLabelArray = [String]()
timeWorkLabelArray.appendContentsOf(selectedTime)
```

or

```
var selectedTime = ("00", "00")
var timeWorkLabelArray = [(String, String)]()
timeWorkLabelArray.append(selectedTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedTime = ["00", "00"]
var timeWorkLabelArray = [String]()
timeWorkLabelArray.appendContentsOf(selectedTime)
```

You can't append a tuple to an array declared as `[String]`.